# JSON.stringify does not generate correct json

Tags: javascript, c#, json, charts, google-visualization

I'm having trouble with JSON.stringify because I can't generate the json format of the model I want to convert. Screen below were the result of JSON.stringify and as you can see on the highlighted part some irregularities on the json itself.[image]

Below is my code for populating the model:

```
LookupBase[] lCityLookups = bgReportsUtil.GetLookupCities(_PersonUID, _ClientUID);
JsonResult json = new JsonResult();
json.Data = lCityLookups; //support;
json.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
json.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
return json;
```

Below is my code on javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "SaladEntry/FillData",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json;",
    data: paramSerialized,
    success: function (resultVal) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(resultVal));
});
```

Above issue is solve but this does not totally solve my real issue.
I want to create a chart using google chart then later will create image file of it and save it to server but I'm stuck with this error.
[image]

If you go to the place where the error occurred.
[image]

This is the code on how I create chart.

```
        var arrMain = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < resultVal.length; i++) {
    var arr = [resultVal[i].ScaleMin, resultVal[i].PK, resultVal[i].CountryNo, resultVal[i].stringEffectiveDate, resultVal[i].ScaleMax, String(resultVal[i].Currency)];
    arrMain.push(arr);
    }
    console.log(arrMain);   //to remove
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'ScaleMin');
    data.addColumn('string', 'PK');
    data.addColumn('number', 'CountryNo');
    data.addColumn('string', 'stringEffectiveDate');
    data.addColumn('number', 'ScaleMax');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Currency');
    data.addRows(arrMain);

    var options = {
'title': 'Title',
'width': 800,
'height': 600
};
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
chart_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
});
chart.draw(data, options);
$.ajax({
url: "SaladEntry/SaveToLocal",
type: "POST",
data: { 'jsonData': chart.getImageURI() },
success: function (ret) {
alert(ret);
}
});
```

Comment: What are the original values that supposed to be converted?

Comment: Kermit seems like he has the right answer, you're returning JSON and then trying to stringify it to JSON again.

Comment: I update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as stated in the error, you're trying to get the chart's image, before the chart has been drawn

move the ajax post inside the chart's `'ready'` event...

see following snippet...

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
  chart_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';

  $.ajax({
    url: "SaladEntry/SaveToLocal",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 'jsonData': chart.getImageURI() },
    success: function (ret) {
      alert(ret);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`resultVal` have already been stringified,you can directly call `alert(resultVal)`;